# VBA: Error thrown when using Or (In an If-Then statement), the first condition tests if object is nothing

Tags: vba, if-statement, short-circuiting

For a custom object, I want to test two conditions. The first is whether the object is nothing. If so, enter the block. If the object is not nothing, I want to do a test on one of the object's properties, and only enter the block if it passes this test.

So the statement would by akin to:

```
If myObject Is Nothing Or myObject.myInt > x Then
    'Perform my task
End If
```

If myObject is in fact nothing, this throws an error, since when it tests the second condition, it tries to access a property of an object that isn't there.

Most languages I've worked with in the past would not bother to test the second condition of an Or statement if it found the first condition to be true, so you could get away with writing the line above. VBA doesn't seem to allow this. Is there any equivalent way i could write this statement, without resorting to:

```
If myObject Is Nothing Then
    'Perform my task
ElseIf myObject.myInt > x Then
    'Perform my task
End If
```

?

EDITED FOR CLARITY

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a flag:

```
PerformTheTask = False

If myObject Is Nothing Then
    PerformTheTask = True
ElseIf myObject.myInt > x Then
    PerformTheTask = True
End If

If PerformTheTask Then
    'Perform my task
End If
```

Comment: Thanks, DJ, this is probably the most efficient way to do it, short of putting the task in a separate subroutine (which I think is overkill, it's only a few lines)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't help you resolve your code issue, but I thought I'd include a pointer to the Wikipedia page on short-circuit operator evaluation:

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

It includes a useful table of common operators in common languages, classifying whether they abide by short-circuit semantics or always evaluate eagerly.  In the specific base of VBA, they confirm that the operands to `And` and `Or` are indeed *eagerly* evaluated.

Comment: Glad to know it wasn't my imagination. Interesting read, that.

Comment: @Swiftslide FWIW, it also comes as a surprise to me that VBA doesn't implement short-circuited `And` or `Or`...

Comment: It's funny. I always assumed that once you learn the syntax, all programming languages operated pretty much the same way. This reminds me of learning C++ and pointers, when the I knew before that was Java :/

Answer (score 1):

While it's a little unusual, you could also do the following:

```
Select Case True
    Case myObject Is Nothing, myObject.myInt > x
        'Perform task
End Select
```

Select implicit comparisons will use short-circuit evaluation. "Or" won't.

Comment: By *could* I mean that it's possible, not that it's necessarily a good idea :)

Comment: Finally, the only reason it mightn't be a good idea would be if you or someone else might come back to it and find it unclear.

Comment: That's a pretty damn good reason for never, ever doing this... Still, +1 for pointing out this quirky construct, and giving others the opportunity to reemphasize that unreadable code like this is a major pain to work with.

Comment: Haha, @Jean-FrançoisCorbett, I just meant to point out that there is only one reason I can see that you wouldn't use this, not that that reason isn't a good one :)